# Running POST request to php script which sends contact mail from within wordpress subfolder results in 404 Not found

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I've just read so much about this issue, but I'm lost here. Can't make this s*$%& work. Here's the issue. Graphic designer has a working WordPress, of which I know same as nothing, about some kindergarten in the city. She builds a landing page to throw a marketing campaign within a subfolder `landing201812` inside the public_html folder of the hosting space. The WordPress is installed/deployed/whatever at the root of the site.

Site: https://www.newmills.com.ar/

Landing: https://www.newmills.com.ar/landing201812/

Directories:

```
public_html/
 - lots_of_wordpress_rubbish
 - .htaccess
 - landing201812/
    - sendform.php
```

Reading about wordpress bootstrapping way for processing all the requests, I have altered the `.htaccess` file in public_html so it excludes the rewriting of wordpress and goes straight to the landing site.

Original content:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Actual content

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^landing201812/?.* - [L] # My added rule
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

With both configurations, the static content (html/css/media) is served correctly, but, any php I would like to execute within that landing201812 folder, fails with a 404 Not Found error. I have tried also to exclude any landing201812 route with RewriteCond directives from the last RewriteRule like

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*landing201812.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

But the results are the same.

I am quite limited to move around the wordpress since I know nothing about wordpress. I have considered moving it to a subfolder of the public_html, but I'm afraid of breaking it, or its URLs. I have tried to disable the permalinks, but there's no `On/Off` switch that I could find.

Last, but in case you may wonder, I have tried including another .htaccess file inside my landing201812 folder. `RewriteEngine Off` did not work as much as the alternative I took from a native wordpress subfolder:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /landing201812/
RewriteRule ^.*\.php$ - [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

So... does anyone know what's wrong, or even better, how to fix this issue? Everyone says on the web that I should be fine with the htaccess rule, or disabling the permalinks, or moving the wordpress to a subfolder and not the root folder. Moving it is the last thing I would like to do, because I won't know how to fix it if it breaks. Am I missing something? Is there any log I should check?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using cpanel, this is not necessary to do in .htaccess
Instead, can you please keep the original wordpress .htaccess and just assign permissions with filezilla to 775 to the folder?
Also, there should be a configuration missmatch, please try re-loading the PHP version in CPANEL (with PHP MANAGER) only to that folder.

If you can provide access to the site in private, maybe I can give you a hand.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that if you were to keep the origional WordPress .htaccess and change your file structure to the following it will work at `/landing201812/`:

```
public_html/
 - lots_of_wordpress_rubbish (not my opinion, just here to match OP)
 - .htaccess
 - landing201812/
    - index.php
```

The key is naming the file `index.php`. Otherwise, you can call the file by name like so:  `/landing201812/sendform.php`.